# How to solve flutter page is not showing properly

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am currently working on an E-Commerce app. I have made my **Homepage** which shows the available products and a **HomeDetailPage** which shows the details of a single product when a user clicks on a particular product. Now the problem is my entire app is working finely in my **Pixel-5 Emulator** but the HomeDetailPage is not Working in my actual device when I install the app in my personal phone. I am currently using Samsung A50 as my actual device I dont understand what is wrong in this code
**Here is the Code For Homepage:-**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/pages/homedetal.dart';

import 'package:flutter_application_1/products.dart';

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Homepage> createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  getdata() async {
    var catalogdata = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/files/products.json");
    var catalogjson = await jsonDecode(catalogdata);
    var productdata = catalogjson["products"];
    ProductsModel.productlist =
        List.from(productdata).map<Item>((item) => Item.fromMap(item)).toList();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    getdata();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        // key: ProductsModel.scaffoldKey,
        body: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 32.0, left: 32.0, top: 32.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'TonyShop',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 45,
                      color: Colors.deepPurple,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/login");
                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_forward,
                      color: Colors.deepPurple,
                    ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.only(right: 32.0, left: 32.0, bottom: 32.0),
            child: Text(
              'Trending products',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.deepPurple,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          // SizedBox(
          //   height: 20,
          // ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: ProductsModel.productlist.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final catalog = ProductsModel.productlist[index];

                return Material(
                  child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  HomeDetailPage(singleitem: catalog),
                            ));
                      },
                      child:
                          Itemwidget(item: ProductsModel.productlist[index])),
                );
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class Itemwidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Item item;
  const Itemwidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.item,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Itemwidget> createState() => _ItemwidgetState();
}

class _ItemwidgetState extends State<Itemwidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 120,
                  width: 120,
                  child: Hero(
                      tag: Key(widget.item.id.toString()),
                      child: Image.network(widget.item.image)),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 200,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          widget.item.name,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text(
                            widget.item.desc,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                          ),
                          width: 150,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        ButtonBar(
                          buttonPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                          alignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              widget.item.price.toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => HomeDetailPage(
                                            singleitem: widget.item)));
                              },
                              style: ButtonStyle(
                                  backgroundColor:
                                      MaterialStateProperty.all(Color.fromRGBO(
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    1,
                                  )),
                                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                      RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(16.0)))),
                              child: Text(
                                "Buy",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**And Here is my Code for HomeDetailPage:-**

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/pages/home.dart';

import 'package:flutter_application_1/products.dart';

class HomeDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeDetailPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.singleitem,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final Item singleitem;

  @override
  State<HomeDetailPage> createState() => _HomeDetailPageState();
}

class _HomeDetailPageState extends State<HomeDetailPage> {
  Future<bool> _previousroute() {
    // important trick to handle backbutton press;
    return Future(() => Navigator.canPop(context));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Variables for getting the height and width of the screen
    double h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => _previousroute(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            shadowColor: Colors.white,
            elevation: 0,
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
              color: Colors.black,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            )),
        // key: ProductsModel.scaffoldKey,
        body: Container(
          height: h,
          child: Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  ClipPath(
                    clipper: Clipper(),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 240, 240, 245),
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                        child: Hero(
                            tag: Key(widget.singleitem.id.toString()),
                            child: Image.network(widget.singleitem.image)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          widget.singleitem.name,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 30,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Text(
                      widget.singleitem.desc,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0, right: 4.0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: w,
                        // box decoration does not work with button
                        // decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (context) {
                                  return Container(
                                      child: AlertDialog(
                                    actions: [
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                        child: Text(
                                          "Your Order Is On The Way",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 30,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                        children: [
                                          Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                            child: ElevatedButton(
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                // Used to create ok button
                                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                              },
                                              style: ButtonStyle(
                                                  backgroundColor:
                                                      MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                                          Color.fromRGBO(
                                                    0,
                                                    0,
                                                    0,
                                                    1,
                                                  )),
                                                  shape: MaterialStateProperty
                                                      .all(RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                          borderRadius:
                                                              BorderRadius
                                                                  .circular(
                                                                      16.0)))),
                                              child: Text(
                                                "Ok",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 20,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.bold),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ));
                                });
                          },
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                              backgroundColor:
                                  MaterialStateProperty.all(Color.fromRGBO(
                                0,
                                0,
                                0,
                                1,
                              )),
                              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                      RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                              ))),
                          child: Text(
                            "Buy",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 25,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Clipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    // TODO: implement getClip
    var path = new Path();
    // fixed or unchanged points of the container
    path.lineTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height - 20);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        //point creating the curve radius
        size.width / 2,
        size.height + 20,
        // starting point of the curve
        0,
        size.height - 20);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    // TODO: implement shouldReclip
    return false;
  }
}
```

**Here is my Products model class**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProductsModel {
  static List productlist = [];
  static final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey =
      GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
}

class Item {
  late final int id;
  late final String name;
  late final String desc;
  late final int price;
  late final String color;
  late final String image;
  Item({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.desc,
    required this.price,
    required this.color,
    required this.image,
  });
  factory Item.fromMap(map) {
    return Item(
        id: map["id"],
        name: map["name"],
        desc: map["desc"],
        price: map["price"],
        color: map["color"],
        image: map["image"]);
  }
}
```

**In case that if you want to try this yourself Here is my dummy product.json file code for you:-**

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "iPhone 12 Pro",
            "desc": "Apple iPhone 12th generation",
            "price": 999,
            "color": "#33505a",
            "image": "https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4982/as-images.apple.com/is/iphone-12-pro-blue-hero?wid=940&hei=1112&fmt=png-alpha&qlt=80&.v=1604021661000"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Pixel 5",
            "desc": "Google Pixel phone 5th generation",
            "price": 699,
            "color": "#00ac51",
            "image": "https://www.telstra.com.au/content/dam/tcom/lego/2020/plans-devices/mobiles/google-pixel-5/shared-google-pixel-5-black-05-900x1200.png"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "M1 Macbook Air",
            "desc": "Apple Macbook air with apple silicon",
            "price": 1099,
            "color": "#e0bfae",
            "image": "https://support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/SP825/macbookair.png"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Playstation 5",
            "desc": "Sony Playstation 5th generation",
            "price": 500,
            "color": "#544ee4",
            "image": "https://i1.wp.com/freepngimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Playstation-5-games-console-transparent-background-png-image.png?fit=1000%2C1000"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Airpods Pro",
            "desc": "Apple Aipods Pro 1st generation",
            "price": 200,
            "color": "#e3e4e9",
            "image": "https://crdms.images.consumerreports.org/c_lfill,w_598/prod/products/cr/models/400116-wireless-portable-headphones-apple-airpods-pro-10009323.png"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "iPad Pro",
            "desc": "Apple iPad Pro 2020 edition",
            "price": 799,
            "color": "#f73984",
            "image": "https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4982/as-images.apple.com/is/ipad-pro-12-select-wifi-silver-202003_FMT_WHH?wid=940&hei=1112&fmt=png-alpha&qlt=80&.v=1583551131102"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Galaxy S21 Ultra",
            "desc": "Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra 2021 edition",
            "price": 1299,
            "color": "#1c1c1c",
            "image": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/qRQPjHrhRVIs-xnfNSyiPXOH2vH97ylMacgbTKebqJtRfNH3LlYo8pN-5igsLDWUH62tGl5zNpTsl5xd8SprzGmXoCEmWFOi2-2cQVGS-r3PaRXHt62DmJHq-jrYX0UQvWZ9BA=s800-c"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Galaxy S21",
            "desc": "Samsung Galaxy S21 2021 edition",
            "price": 899,
            "color": "#7c95eb",
            "image": "https://images.samsung.com/is/image/samsung/p6pim/za/galaxy-s21/gallery/za-clear-cover-galaxy-s21-5g-ef-qg991ttegww-363168624?$720_576_PNG$"
        }
    ]
}
```

**In my emulator it looks like this** [Emulator Image](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1ciEBz5srcfctiFKHY0zqrh86CBdqqOuP)
**In my Device it looks like this** [Device Image](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1QVWXBZtPhphqY9z9OfLIMa2vG42R3_rp)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of expanded widget in HomeDetailsScreen, you can use Flexible instead of expanded like that:

```
Flexible(
fit: FlexFit.tight,
  child: ...,
);
```

Comment: I have already used a scaffold here . Do you want me to use it again?

Comment: Sorry, I got mixed up but I edited it

Comment: Please try that and let me know if it's working

Comment: In my emulator it looks like this <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1ciEBz5srcfctiFKHY0zqrh86CBdqqOuP" alt="emulator Image" width="500" height="600">

Comment: And in ur real device ?

Comment: Is it a grey screen ?

Comment: Yes @Shimaa Yasser

Comment: In my Device it is a grey screen with an white appbar and a back arrow button

Comment: I have provided image links for you below my main post @Shimaa Yasser

Comment: It's because of expanded widget in HomeDetailsScreen, you can use Flexible instead of expanded like I showed you in my answer

Comment: I used Flexible instead of expanded but still facing the problem please help me @Shimaa Yasser

Comment: Did you edit it in HomeDetailPage ?

Comment: Yes I edited it in my HomeDetailPage . Should I edit my main post code of HomeDetailPage for you?

Comment: And you still get a grey screen in HomeDetailPage ?

Comment: Yes It is still showing a grey screen . I have updated my main post's code for you

Comment: I connected my real device with my computer and then applyed this code and it worked for me

Comment: Actually it is working as a debug.apk file but not working as release.apk

Comment: It's because of expanded widget, rebuild a new release apk and let me updated